# Callback in React has original props from first render, not the render when the callback is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: The solution is to redefine the callback on each render by redefining the `timeline.on` outside the effect, but I don't understand why this is necessary still.

Edit 2: I've realized I need to re-add and remove all listeners for each render. Here is the working code. I still don't understand the scoping concept on why the original question doesn't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onSelect = (properties: { items: IdType[]; event: MouseEvent }) => {
      if (!(properties.items.length > 0)) return;
      const selectedItem = items.find(item => item.id === properties.items[0]);
      if (selectedItem) onItemSelect(selectedItem);
    };

    const addListeners = (listenerTimeline: VisTimeline) => {
      listenerTimeline.on('select', onSelect);
    };

    const removeListeners = (listenerTimeline: VisTimeline) => {
      return () => {
        listenerTimeline.off('select', onSelect);
      };
    };

    if (timeline) {
      addListeners(timeline);
      return removeListeners(timeline);
    }
    if (!timeline) {
      const newTimeline = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
      addListeners(newTimeline);
      setTimeline(newTimeline);
      return removeListeners(newTimeline);
    }
  }, [timeline, items, groups, time.start, time.end, onItemSelect]);
```

---

Original Post:

The code in question is here:

```
export const Timeline: FunctionComponent<TimelineProps> = ({
  items,
  groups,
  time,
  onItemSelect,
}) => {

const [timeline, setTimeline] = useState<VisTimeline | undefined>(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    const options: TimelineOptions = {};
    if (!timeline) { // This succeeds only on the first render, and at this time the items prop is an empty array.
      const newTimeline = new VisTimeline(container.current, items, groups, options);
      newTimeline.on('select', (properties: { items: IdType[]; event: MouseEvent }) => {

        console.log(`items: ${items}`); // This logs an empty array, but there is an array of data in this prop when the callback is called

        if (!(properties.items.length > 0)) return; // This is good, has an id of an object
        const selectedItem = items.find(item => item.id === properties.items[0]);
        if (selectedItem) onItemSelect(selectedItem);
      });
      setTimeline(newTimeline);
    }
  }, [timeline, items, groups, time.start, time.end, onItemSelect]);
```

The first time this is rendered, the `useEffect` is called and gets past the first `if` statement. It will only run one time because for each subsequent render `timeline` is already defined and this effect exits.

The `items` prop is an empty array when the effect is run. However, when the callback is called (much later) the `items` prop is an array with data in it to search. I have verified this in the React Dev Tools.

What `newTimeline.on` does is register a callback that occurs when an item in my timeline is selected.

So while the `items` prop has an array with data, for whatever reason the `items` variable in the scope of the callback is still the original empty array from the first render this ran.

It's an arrow function, but does the callback capture it's environment when it is called the first time and not re-evaluate later? Thanks for any help.